# Error with pylibmc on Mac OS Lion

Tags: python, memcached, osx-lion

I have a problem with pylibmc on Mac OS Lion.

libmemcached — 1.0.4

pylibmc — 1.2.3

```
$ python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 25 2011, 05:09:01) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pylibmc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pylibmc/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    import _pylibmc
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_pylibmc.so, 2): Symbol not found: _memcached_add
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_pylibmc.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_pylibmc.so
```

But it works with sudo!

```
$ sudo python
Password:
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 25 2011, 05:09:01) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pylibmc
>>>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Installation in 32-bit mode solved the problem.

1. You need to install libevent in 32-bit mode

   ```
   brew install --universal libevent
   ```
2. Next to download libmemcached source (1.0.8 version works for me) and configure force for 32 bit arch:

   ```
   ./configure --build=i386-apple-darwin11.4.2 "CFLAGS=-m32" "CXXFLAGS=-m32" "LDFLAGS=-m32"
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

   where 11.4.2 is the version of kernel
3. Reinstall pylibmc

   ```
   sudo pip uninstall pylibmc
   sudo pip install pylibmc
   ```
4. Now it works

   ```
   $ python -c 'import pylibmc'
   $
   ```

Comment: I tried this but it failed in `libmemcached`'s `make` step. Then I tried `brew install libmemcached` and it works.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a build and/or installation problem with libmemcached. Maybe you can check out issue #101? https://github.com/lericson/pylibmc/issues/101